# What's the difference between polarization ratio ρ_C and ρ_L?

Tags: antenna, polarity

I have the following 2 equations in my textbook:

ρ_L = E_Φ/E_θ

ρ_C = E_R/E_L = (1 + jρ_L)/(1 - jρ_L)

Both ρ_L and ρ_C are called polarization ratio. However, what's the difference between the two?